# How do I dictate the order of how tests are run while running espresso tests for my android app?

Tags: android-espresso

Upon running the test class, the tests inside the class are run randomly not in the order I have written them and which where causing a cache which I solved with orchestrator

I expected the test to run based on the order in which I wrote them in the test class

Comment: Generally the order of test should explicitly NOT matter.

Comment: Thank you. I'll then just proceed with writing tests having it in mind that they are independent. 

However, this was in line with the UI tests. 
Don't you think, since some UI rendering depends on some previous states of the Ui and data fed in, will it be able to execute rightfully?